# Python string range (parsing html)

Tags: python, html, parsing

In python I have copied a webpage and want to get all occurrences of `<a href=`

I am using urllib2 and my setup is as follows:

```
import urllib2
response = urllib2.urlopen("http://python.org")
html = response.read()
```

What would be the best way to approach this task? How would I select a range of string text from a variable that has stored the entire webpage?

Comment: +1 for *not* mentioning regular expressions :-)

Comment: Is Beautiful soup also capable of finding emails, phone numbers, etc?

Comment: Uh-oh! What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For parsing HTML in Python, I prefer [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/). This is assuming you want to find links, and not just the literal `<a href=`, which you can easily do searching through the string.

Comment: Wow; BeautifulSoup is phenomenal

Answer (score 3):

This is a job for [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) for sure:

```
>>> from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
>>> import urllib2
>>> page = urllib2.urlopen('http://stackoverflow.com/')
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
>>> links = soup.html.body.findAll('a', limit=10)
>>> for i, link in enumerate(links):
...     print i, ':', link.text, ' -- ', link['href'] 
... 
0 : Stack Exchange  --  http://stackexchange.com
1 : log in  --  /users/login
2 : blog  --  http://blog.stackoverflow.com
3 : careers  --  http://careers.stackoverflow.com
4 : chat  --  http://chat.stackoverflow.com
5 : meta  --  http://meta.stackoverflow.com
6 : about  --  /about
7 : faq  --  /faq
8 : Stack Overflow  --  /
9 : Questions  --  /questions
```

There are a lot of links on that front-page; I've limited the output to the first ten!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need an HTML Parser. Look into [Beautiful Soup](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/BeautifulSoup/3.2.0). I wouldn't use Regular Expressions, it gets awfully messy, and is error prone.

Answer (score 0):

You could for instance use a regular expression to match HTML links or subclass Python's builtin SGML parser:

```
from sgmllib import SGMLParser

class URLExtractor(SGMLParser):
    def reset(self):
        SGMLParser.reset(self)
        self.urls = []

    def start_a(self, attrs):
        for name, value in attrs:
            if name == 'href':
                self.urls.append(value)
```

You would use it like that:

```
extractor = URLExtractor()
extractor.feed(html)
print extractor.urls
```

Answer (score 0):

Another +1 for Beautiful Soup. That said, if you really want a dirt simple parser, you can always use good ol' regular expression searching.

```
>>> import urllib2
>>> response = urllib2.urlopen("http://python.org")
>>> html = response.read()

>>> import re
>>> re.findall("<a[^>]*href=[^>]*>", html)
```

NOTE: Updated regex to be more accurate based on comment

Comment: What about links like `<a title="Blah" href="/path/to/blah/">`?

Comment: Sure - the above example was mostly a first pass. I'm sure I missed some edge cases. You could probably do re.findall("<a[^>]*href=[^>]*>", html) to be more accurate. And again - Beautiful Soup is probably a better solution anyway.